# How to map docker ports using vagrant 1.6 and the docker provider

Tags: vagrant, docker, vagrantfile, boot2docker

I'm currently trying to map my docker container ports from the container to the host (boot2docker). The end goal is to map those ports to my physical machine, but one step at a time.

My Vagrantfile currently looks like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.define "app1" do |a|
        a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.build_dir = "dockers/app1"
            d.name = "app1"
            d.ports << "8080:8080"
            d.ports << "8443:8443"
            d.volumes << "/vagrant/data/app1:/var/app1"
        end
    end

    config.vm.define "app2" do |a|
        a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.build_dir = "dockers/app2"
            d.name = "app2"
            d.ports << "8081:8081"
            d.link("app1:app1")
        end
    end
end
```

When I run `vagrant up app1 --provider=docker` the container spins up correctly, however when I do a docker ps I can see that ports have not been mapped.

```
0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8443/tcp
```

I am using VirtualBox, so I have used it GUI to port forward my physical machines `8080` to the hosts (boot2docker) `8080`.

Comment: can you paste the output of a docker inspect ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forward Ports from boot2docker using the Vagrant Docker provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948831/forward-ports-from-boot2docker-using-the-vagrant-docker-provider)

Comment: Are you using Vagrant 1.6.0 or 1.6.1? It looks like this may have been an issue that was fixed in 1.6.2: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3723

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration should work on Linux, but if you're using a Virtualbox (I assume you're on Mac or Windows), then you want a Vagrantfile for your VM to get it to your host.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "busybox"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 768
    v.cpus = 2
  end

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port,
    guest: 8080, host: 8080

end
```

Let's pretend that's in host-vm/Vagrantfile relative to your current Vagrantfile. So your current Vagrantfile should look like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.define "app1" do |a|
        a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host-vm/Vagrantfile"
            d.build_dir = "dockers/app1"
            d.name = "app1"
            d.ports = ["8080:8080"]
            d.ports = ["8443:8443"]
            d.create_args = ["-v", "/vagrant/data/app1:/var/app1"]
        end
    end

    config.vm.define "app2" do |a|
        a.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "host-vm/Vagrantfile"
            d.build_dir = "dockers/app2"
            d.name = "app2"
            d.ports = ["8081:8081"]
            d.link("app1:app1")
        end
    end
end
```