# How do I SSH into the boot2docker host vm that the Vagrant 1.6 Docker Provider sets up?

Tags: vagrant, docker, boot2docker

I'm on OSX and I'd like to be able to SSH into the host vm in order to:

1. Get access to a native docker environment. This facilitates understanding and debugging port forwarding issues.
2. Vagrant rsync seems to leave a lot of unused synced directories that's eating up disk space that I'd like to recover.

To be clear, this question is NOT about ssh:ing into the docker containers that the Vagrant provider creates, but into the intermediate boot2docker host vm that Vagrant creates.

I know that a workaround is to not use the default boot2docker as the host vm (as explained in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948831/forward-ports-from-boot2docker-using-the-vagrant-docker-provider)), but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: What about `vagrant ssh`?

Comment: That would ssh into the docker container provisioned by the Vagrant docker provider, but not into the boot2docker host vm itself

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Vagrant's boot2docker keeps boot2docker's ssh username and password.

> #### SSH into VM
>
> ```
> $ boot2docker ssh
> ```
>
> Boot2Docker auto logs in using the generated SSH key, but if you want to SSH into
>   the machine manually (or you're not using a `boot2docker` managed VM), the credentials are:
>
> ```
> user: docker
> pass: tcuser
> ```

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#ssh-into-vm

The port is forwarded from the local port `2022` by default. You can verify this:

```
$ VBoxManage list vms | grep docker
"docker-host_default_1234567890000_1234" {3d66ecf6-4539-47ca-afd2-66f953cd9a3e}
$ VBoxManage showvminfo docker-host_default_1234567890000_1234 | grep ssh
NIC 1 Rule(1):   name = ssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 2022, guest ip = , guest port = 22
```

And then login:

```
$ ssh docker@localhost -p 2022
docker@localhost's password: tcuser
                        ##        .
                  ## ## ##       ==
               ## ## ## ##      ===
           /""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o          __/
             \    \        __/
              \____\______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
boot2docker: 0.8.0
docker@boot2docker:~$
```

Comment: This has changed from `boot2docker` to `docker-machine` in latest Docker

Comment: specifically, it's now `docker-machine ssh default`

Comment: this helps if you want to ssh from a mobaXterm or any other ssh client

Answer (score 15):

Oct 2015: Boot2docker is deprecated in favor of docker-machine. To login:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376   

$ docker-machine ssh default
```

Comment: This is the easiest and newest way to go now.

Answer (score 11):

You can ssh into docker host with `vagrant ssh docker-host-id` but first you need to know the docker-host-id.
You can get a list of all active Vagrant environments with `vagrant global-status` command.
To get the docker-host id you can filter with grep:

`vagrant global-status | grep docker-host`

you'll obtain an output similar to:

```
68f58d0  default  virtualbox running   /Users/yourUser/.vagrant.d/data/docker-host
```

copy the first column id, and then ssh into docker-host:

`vagrant ssh 68f58d0`

[vagrant global status docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/global-status.html)

Comment: I believe this is the best answer. I have "regular" boot2docker, and I have the boot2docker that Vagrant started. The other answers connect me to the "regular" boot2docker machine, not the one that Vagrant is using.

Answer (score 7):

You can also forgo using `boot2docker`'s `ssh` function and do it "manually" like so:

```
$ ssh \
-i $HOME/.ssh/id_boot2docker \
-p $(boot2docker config 2>&1 | awk '/SSHPort/ {print $3}') \
docker@localhost
```

The arguments to `-p` is typically port 2022 but above shows how you can programmatically determine this if you want.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use SSH directly:**

```
ssh docker@$(boot2docker ip)
```

(password: tcuser, see https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#ssh-into-vm)

---

And you can also copy/paste your public key to the boot2docker machine, so you don't need to type the password every time:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh docker@$(boot2docker ip) 'cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: You can use the generated identify file as well. "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_boot2docker docker@$(boot2docker ip) "

Answer (score 2):

For vagrant host machines with *vagrant* password:

```
ssh -p 2222 vagrant@localhost
```

Otherwise with *tcuser* password:

```
ssh -p 2222 docker@localhost
```

[Here](https://coderwall.com/p/m3java/vagrant-ssh-into-docker-controller) is more information on why this works.