# docker-machine boot2docker root password

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

Haven't found an answer anywhere... I created a VM (boot2docker) using docker-machine. I need to edit some files using root.

What is the root password in boot2docker?

Comment: have you tried this: `tcuser` ?

Comment: yes, but wrong password

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286007/how-do-i-ssh-into-the-boot2docker-host-vm-that-the-vagrant-1-6-docker-provider-s

Comment: user: **docker** and pwd: **tcuser** then `sudo`

Comment: @MediaVince that works, but where does that information come from?

Comment: Nevermind, the reference is [boot2docker README](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/README.md#ssh-into-vm), as said in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646952/docker-machine-boot2docker-root-password#comment92080055_47307040)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you only have a single docker machine, you simply do:

```
$ docker-machine ssh
```

If you have multiple machines, you need to find your "machine name" first:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v1.10.2
```

From the above, you can see that **default** is the name of your machine and you can ssh as follows:

```
$ docker-machine ssh default
```

When you're in, it's a simple case of sudo-ing to root

```
docker@default:~$ sudo -i
Boot2Docker version 1.10.2, build master : 611be10 - Mon Feb 22 22:47:06 UTC 2016
Docker version 1.10.2, build c3959b1
root@default:~#
```

Edited: Also, as @MediaVince mentioned you can use the following credentials:

user: **docker**

pwd: **tcuser**

Comment: why does -i work ? I know it means "simulate initial login", but what is the exact mechanism ?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the user's question. The answer was in his question's comment.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The -i executes a login shell, similar to the user login in. The manual includes a more complete explanation: Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

Answer (score 31):

just type

```
$ docker-machine ssh your_environment
```

and then to be root

```
$ sudo -i
```

hope it helps

Comment: why does -i work ? I know it means "simulate initial login", but what is the exact mechanism ?

Answer (score 21):

Login via ssh as `docker` user:

```
$ ssh docker@<docker-machine-ip>
```

> Password: tcuser

Then you can change on `root` user, just run `sudo su root`

Comment: This is also documented at https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Ok the key was not to do "su root" but rather "su sudo". It then doesn't ask for root password.

Comment: For me it was rather `sudo su`. `su sudo` gives `su: unknown user sudo`