# Docker: How to clear the logs properly for a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, docker-machine

I use `docker logs [container-name]` to see the logs of a specific container.

Is there an elegant way to clear these logs?

Comment: On a sidenote, you can get the size of the logs via `sudo sh -c "du -ch /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log"`

Comment: Not exactly clearing the logs, but to avoid seeing the old logs you can use "-n" and the "-f" option.
-n: Number of lines to show from the end of the logs (default "all")
-f: Follow log output
$ docker logs -n 0 -f [container-name]
This will show you incoming logs only

Comment: If you tried all the answers but `docker logs foo` is still showing several lines, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76377582/3957754

Comment: From [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/): "**Warning** The `json-file` logging driver uses file-based storage. These files are designed to be exclusively accessed by the Docker daemon. Interacting with these files with external tools may interfere with Docker's logging system and result in unexpected behavior, and should be avoided".  This means that answers that suggest to simply truncate the log file must be considered **wrong**.

Answer (score 729, accepted):

First the bad answer. From [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/637996/351549) there's a one-liner that you can run:

```
echo "" > $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)
```

instead of echo, there's the simpler:

```
: > $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)
```

or there's the truncate command:

```
truncate -s 0 $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)
```

---

I'm not a big fan of either of those since they modify Docker's files directly. The external log deletion could happen while docker is writing json formatted data to the file, resulting in a partial line, and breaking the ability to read any logs from the `docker logs` cli. For an example of that happening, see [this comment on duketwo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510002/how-to-clear-the-logs-properly-for-a-docker-container/42510314?noredirect=1#comment98713207_43570083):

> after emptying the logfile, I get this error: `error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value`

Instead, you can have Docker automatically rotate the logs for you. This is done with additional flags to dockerd if you are using the default [JSON logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/):

```
dockerd ... --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=3
```

You can also set this as part of your [daemon.json](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#on-linux) file instead of modifying your startup scripts:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {"max-size": "10m", "max-file": "3"}
}
```

These options need to be configured with root access. Make sure to run a `systemctl reload docker` after changing this file to have the settings applied. This setting will then be the default for any newly created containers. Note, existing containers need to be deleted and recreated to receive the new log limits.

---

Similar log options can be passed to individual containers to override these defaults, allowing you to save more or fewer logs on individual containers. From `docker run` this looks like:

```
docker run --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=3 ...
```

or in a compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    image: ...
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
```

---

For additional space savings, you can switch from the json log driver to the "local" log driver. It takes the same max-size and max-file options, but instead of storing in json it uses a binary syntax that is faster and smaller. This allows you to store more logs in the same sized file. The daemon.json entry for that looks like:

```
{
  "log-driver": "local",
  "log-opts": {"max-size": "10m", "max-file": "3"}
}
```

The downside of the local driver is external log parsers/forwarders that depended on direct access to the json logs will no longer work. So if you use a tool like filebeat to send to Elastic, or Splunk's universal forwarder, I'd avoid the "local" driver.

I've got a bit more on this in my [Tips and Tricks presentation](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2019/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#logs).

Comment: I did a `service docker restart`  which on its own did not work.  Also had to brand create new containers before it took effect.  i.e. just bringing up the old containers did not apply the new logging

Comment: I am using Docker 1.13.1, and the 'docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container id>' returns a null string ("")....but I am still getting output from 'docker logs <container id>'?!?  Where is that coming from and how do I clear it??

Comment: @JDAllen 1.13.1 is long out of support. I don't have a system that old to view their inspect output.

Comment: Better yet would be `echo -n > ...`. Anyway, I would like to be able to have more control over my logs. For instance, after *docker-compose* restart, I would love to have the mechanism to do something with the preserved logs.

Comment: @NarūnasK It's an open source project, you can submit a PR. Probably easier to write a wrapper around your calls to `docker-compose`

Comment: One way to use the `echo "" >...` safely, though, is to stop docker first. Run that `echo` command, then restart docker. I suppose that stopping docker may not be an option to some, of course. Also you need to ask docker for the filename before you stop it and run the echo as root or use `sudo truncate -s 9 <filename>` as shown by others.

Comment: @AlexisWilke if you're able to stop docker, then you're likely able to stop your container. If you can do the latter, then recreating the container with the logging options would be my advice. The new container has no old logs, and new logs will be rolled automatically, solving both the short term and long term issue at the same time.

Comment: This doesn't work if the container is so old it has rotated the logs. Only the 2nd answer will fix that but will wipe all container logs and not only 1

Comment: Worked running as `sudo su`

Comment: @Vitaliy reiterating my comment above, if you can stop the container, you should also be able to recreate the container with options to automatically rotate the logs.

Comment: @BMitch, this is not what I always want - many times in a test environment I want the log to collect as much information as possible, and only once in a while to reset it.

Comment: a one-liner, why not: docker ps|awk {'print $1'}|xargs docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' |xargs truncate -s 0 | because u can add "|grep" between in case u only want to purge specific containers...

Comment: The problem is that in all likelihood the user will be trying to clear the logs so that they can identify relevant output; rotating logs does not address this issue at all (a smaller log with 3000 lines is just as useless as one with 30000), unless a method to force the rotation manually is provided...

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau this is solving the problem that logs take disk space and grow unconstrained with long running containers. To view logs after a specific time, use `--since`.

Comment: @BMitch Nice! So for logs starting at the time of the command, `docker logs [container_name] --follow --since 0m`

Comment: What if `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>` returns file path (`/var/lib/docker/containers/<id>/<id>-json.log` that does not exist? When I `cat` it, I get _No such file or directory_

Comment: @wscourge did you see the second section of the answer, or only copy and paste the command that described as the "bad answer"?

Comment: I saw it, yet I'm not interested in rotating the logs, as the question states.

Answer (score 494):

Use:

```
truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/**/*-json.log
```

You may need sudo

```
sudo sh -c "truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/**/*-json.log"
```

ref. Jeff S. [Docker: How to clear the logs properly for a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510002/how-to-clear-the-logs-properly-for-a-docker-container#comment86247471_43570083)

Reference: *[Truncating a file while it's being used (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980283/truncating-a-file-while-its-being-used-linux)*

Comment: truncate: cannot open ‘/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log’ for writing: No such file or directory

Comment: @BTRNaidu you have to run it as root/sudo, the content of `containers` is not available otherwise.

Comment: ```sudo sh -c "truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log"``` - worked for me

Comment: You'd have to sudo that as well, that's when the antennas should go out and detect the danger.

Comment: Ignore the two professionals above. If you are unsure, you can just check with "ls /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log" what is being truncated.

Comment: If you happen to do it within a container, then /var/lib/docker is mounted to the container somehow. Be very careful: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22260#issuecomment-263035087

Comment: after emptying the logfile, I get this error: `error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value`

Comment: @BTRNaidu @JeffShillitto @duketwo `sudo sh -c "[command with globs]"` works because that expands the globs *inside* a root shell, rather than as the user running the `sudo` command. If you don't have access to even list the files inside /var/lib/docker/containers/ a glob inside it is just going to expand to itself (unless you `shopt -s nullglob`).

Comment: You need to add `*` after .log to clear logs that have already been rotated but still show up with `docker logs`

Comment: are you sure that it won't delete files inside containers matching the pattern?

Answer (score 105):

On Docker for Windows and Mac, and probably others too, it is possible to use the tail option. For example:

```sh
docker logs -f --tail 100
```

This way, only the last 100 lines are shown, and you don't have first to scroll through 1M lines...

(And thus, deleting the log is probably unnecessary)

Comment: The idea is to clean log files and not to print the last n lines of log files

Comment: some edited my post but the suggestion does not work, at least not on docker 20.10.5 to use 
docker logs -f --since 30s (e.g.)

Comment: if you are only wanting logs from a particular container using docker-compose, you can also use this command: `docker-compose logs --tail 10 --follow service1 service2 etc`

Comment: Downvoted because it does not even attempt to answer the original question

Comment: I found this question looking for a way to stop docker-compose logs -f from endlessly scrolling before reaching the tail. This solution works perfectly for that.

Answer (score 65):

```
sudo sh -c "truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log"
```

Comment: To get the size of the logs `sudo sh -c "du -ch /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log"`, to only get the total of the size of the logs `sudo sh -c "du -ch /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log | grep total"`

Comment: Are there any issues with dockerd/aufs being ignorant of and incapable to remove the rotated log files?

Comment: This command worked for me whereas the other commands in this SO have not. If it matters, I'm running Docker version 18 on CentOS 7

Answer (score 41):

You can set up logrotate to clear the logs periodically.

Example file in /etc/logrotate.d/docker-logs

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log {
 rotate 7
 daily
 compress
 size=50M
 missingok
 delaycompress
 copytruncate
}
```

Comment: and how do i use this? it is used as default with `docker run`? file `/etc/logrotate.d/docker-logs` does not exists, i have to create it?

Comment: You have to call the logrotate utility  (logrotate <config-file> )  and it will read your configuration and run the cleanup. You can also set it as a cron job for example.

Comment: The problem with this one is that it may not be properly synchronized with what docker is doing. Using the docker facility is probably much wiser. (the `"log-opts"` as shown by BMitch)

Comment: `logrotate` might already be set up. On my Ubuntu 20.04 server it’s set as a cron job: `cat /etc/cron.daily/logrotate`. Try `sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf` to do a dry run to see if the newly created `/etc/logrotate.d/docker-logs` does what it should do.

Answer (score 39):

You can also supply the log-opts parameters on the `docker run` command line, like this:

```
docker run --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=5 my-app:latest
```

or in a docker-compose.yml like this

```
my-app:
image: my-app:latest
logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"
```

*Credits: https://medium.com/@Quigley_Ja/rotating-docker-logs-keeping-your-overlay-folder-small-40cfa2155412 (James Quigley)*

Comment: The parameter values should be quoted (i.e. `"5"` and `"10m"`respectively), as shown [here](https://success.docker.com/article/how-to-setup-log-rotation-post-installation) for the global daemon.json file, but it is the same for a docker-compose.yml.  In both cases, it will only affect newly created containers.

Comment: @AdrianW: docker-compose.yml do not need quotes. These are entirely different file formats. And yes, you're right: "docker run" commands and docker-compose parameters do only affect newly created containers - as opposed to the answer here with the most votes which affects only restarted dockerd daemons and is available through root access only. My answer is supposed to show a much simpler and updated path than editing than restarting the entire dockerd process.

Comment: Without quotes, I get: _ERROR: for app  Cannot create container for service app: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field LogConfig.Config of type string_  If I quote like this: `"5"` it works. The `10m` work without quoting indeed.

Comment: Looks like there is a difference between Docker for Windows and Docker for Linux. On the latter, I have to enclose the values in quotes. Not on the former. Updated the description to fit both. Thanks, @AdrianW

Answer (score 21):

Docker4Mac, a 2018 solution:

```
LOGPATH=$(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host alpine:latest nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i -- truncate -s0 $LOGPATH
```

The first line gets the log file path, similar to the accepted answer.

The second line uses `nsenter` that allows you to run commands in the `xhyve` VM that servers as the host for all the docker containers under Docker4Mac. The command we run is the familiar `truncate -s0 $LOGPATH` from non-Mac answers.

If you're using `docker-compose`, the first line becomes:

```
local LOGPATH=$(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $(docker-compose ps -q <service>))
```

and `<service>` is the service name from your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Thanks to https://github.com/justincormack/nsenter1 for the `nsenter` trick.

Comment: And to truncate the logs of all containers you can use a shell wildcard as shown in other answers, so it's just one command: `docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host alpine:latest nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i -- sh -c 'truncate -s0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log'`

Answer (score 12):

You can't do this directly through a Docker command.

You can either limit the log's size, or use a script to delete logs related to a container. You can find scripts examples here (read from the bottom): *[Feature: Ability to clear log history #1083](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1083)*

Check out the [logging section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#logging) of the docker-compose file reference, where you can specify [options](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/#options) (such as log rotation and log size limit) for some logging drivers.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a cross platform solution to clearing docker container logs:

```
docker run --rm -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker alpine sh -c "echo '' > $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' CONTAINER_NAME)"
```

Paste this into your terminal and change `CONTAINER_NAME` to desired container name or id.

Comment: for me this is the only working solution to delete logs when using wsl2 on windows. However it may be caused some configuration problem - theoretically access to docker logs should be available from wsl2 distro (for example ubuntu) however this is not working for me.

Comment: @Nicramus I have trouble with the `-v` option under windows: `docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir C:\Program Files\Git\var: Access is denied.`

Comment: Don't use Git-for-Windows bash(MingW) as it mounts the git installation folder as a virtual root of file system tree. Try Ubuntu for Windows and run docker in that. Or, use Docker for Windows and find out where these log files are located and delete them.

Comment: Worked great on a Linux machine. Thanks!

Comment: Just use powershell 7 core. Please please, pretty please stop using any of the MING/CYGWIN shells they just causing you issues on windows, unless you know why you need them. If you just need them for LINUX commands just add C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin to your path and you will have all the commands you need.

Answer (score 10):

As a **root** user, try to run the following:

```
>  /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log
```

or

```
cat /dev/null > /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log
```

or

```
echo "" > /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log
```

Answer (score 9):

On my Ubuntu servers even as sudo I would get `Cannot open ‘/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log’ for writing: No such file or directory`

But combing the docker inspect and truncate answers worked :

```
sudo truncate -s 0 `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container>`
```

Answer (score 8):

I do prefer this one (from solutions above):

```
truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log
```

However I'm running several systems (Ubuntu 18.x Bionic for example), where this path does not work as expected. Docker is installed through Snap, so the path to containers is more like:

```
truncate -s 0 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/*/*-json.log
```

Answer (score 8):

Sharing this since the other answers seem overly complex.

The easiest way to scrap associate container logs will be to force recreate it.

```bash
docker-compose up -d [container] --force-recreate
```

Then running `docker-compose logs [container]` should result in only new entries since the container came up.

Comment: Mind you, this will also recreate all containers that the current service depends on.

Answer (score 7):

This will delete all logfiles for all containers:

```
sudo find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name "*.log" -delete
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: That won't work as expected. As running container would have file still opened and would continue to write to it. It just won't be visible in directory, but would take disk space. (see linux unlink )

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is helpful for you, but removing the container always helps.

So, if you use docker-compose for your setup, you can simply use `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` instead of `docker-compose restart`. With a proper setup (make sure to use volume mounts for persistent data), you don't lose any data this way.

Sure, this is more than the OP requested. But there are various situations where the other answers cannot help (if using a remote docker server or working on a Windows machine, accessing the underlying filesystem is proprietary and difficult)

Comment: Worked for me. Was helpful because I do have several containers, volumes, docker-compose.yml, etc and this did it "smoothly". I always forget to add the `-d` flag (detatched) when running the up command, so don't forget to do it :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [answer by @BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510314/659077), I've just wrote a shell script to clean logs of all the containers:

```
#!/bin/bash
ids=$(docker ps -a --format='{{.ID}}')
for id in $ids
do
        echo $(docker ps -a --format='{{.ID}} ### {{.Names}} ### {{.Image}}' | fgrep $id)
        truncate -s 0 $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $id)
        ls -llh $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $id)
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Linux/Ubuntu:

If you have several containers and you want to remove just one log but not others.

- (*If you have issues like "Permission denied" do first `sudo su`.*)
- List all containers: `docker ps -a`
- Look for the container you desire and copy the `CONTAINER ID`. Example: `E1X2A3M4P5L6`.
- Containers folders and real names are longer than `E1X2A3M4P5L6` but first 12 characters are those resulted in `docker ps -a`.
- Remove just that log:
  `> /var/lib/docker/containers/E1X2A3M4P5L6*/E1X2A3M4P5L6*-json.log` (Replace `E1X2A3M4P5L6` for your result !! )

As you can see, inside `/containers` are the containers, and logs has the same name but with `-json.log` at the end. You just need to know that first 12 characters, because `*` means "anything".

Comment: Well, I tab complete where you said "*" and it works, thanks.

Comment: And `> /var/lib/...` does not work, but `echo >/var/lib/...` works.

Answer (score 3):

I needed something I could run as one command, instead of having to write `docker ps` and copying over each Container ID and running the command multiple times. I've adapted [BMitch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510314/4240137) and thought I'd share in case someone else may find this useful.

Mixing `xargs` seems to pull off what I need here:

```sh
docker ps --format='{{.ID}}' | \
  xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo > $(docker inspect --format="{{.LogPath}}" {})'
```

This grabs each Container ID listed by `docker ps` (**will erase your logs for any container on that list!**), pipes it into `xargs` and then echoes a blank string to replace the log path of the container.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to store a backup of the log files before deleting them, I have created a script that performs the following actions (you have to run it with sudo) for a specified container:

1. Creates a folder to store compressed log files as backup.
2. Looks for the running container's id (specified by the container's name).
3. Copy the container's log file to a new location (folder in step 1) using a random name.
4. Compress the previous log file (to save space).
5. Truncates the container's log file by certain size that you can define.

**Notes:**

- It uses the **shuf** command. Make sure your linux distribution has it or change it to another bash-supported random generator.
- Before use, change the variable **CONTAINER_NAME** to match your running container; it can be a partial name (doesn't have to be the exact matching name).
- By default it truncates the log file to 10M (10 megabytes), but you can change this size by modifying the variable **SIZE_TO_TRUNCATE**.
- It creates a folder in the path: **/opt/your-container-name/logs**, if you want to store the compressed logs somewhere else, just change the variable **LOG_FOLDER**.
- Run some tests before running it in production.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

############################# Main Variables Definition:
CONTAINER_NAME="your-container-name"
SIZE_TO_TRUNCATE="10M"

############################# Other Variables Definition:
CURRENT_DATE=$(date "+%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
RANDOM_VALUE=$(shuf -i 1-1000000 -n 1)
LOG_FOLDER="/opt/${CONTAINER_NAME}/logs"
CN=$(docker ps --no-trunc -f name=${CONTAINER_NAME} | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2)
LOG_DOCKER_FILE="$(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' ${CN})"
LOG_FILE_NAME="${CURRENT_DATE}-${RANDOM_VALUE}"

############################# Procedure:
mkdir -p "${LOG_FOLDER}"
cp ${LOG_DOCKER_FILE} "${LOG_FOLDER}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}.log"
cd ${LOG_FOLDER}
tar -cvzf "${LOG_FILE_NAME}.tar.gz" "${LOG_FILE_NAME}.log"
rm -rf "${LOG_FILE_NAME}.log"
truncate -s ${SIZE_TO_TRUNCATE} ${LOG_DOCKER_FILE}
```

You can create a cronjob to run the previous script every month. First run:

```sh
sudo crontab -e
```

Type **a** in your keyboard to enter edit mode. Then add the following line:

```sh
0 0 1 * * /your-script-path/script.sh
```

Hit the **escape** key to exit Edit mode. Save the file by typing **:wq** and hitting enter. Make sure the **script.sh** file has execution permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Docker for Mac users, here is the solution:

- 1. Find log file path by:

     `$ docker inspect | grep log`
- 2. SSH into the docker machine( suppose the name is `default`, if not, run `docker-machine ls` to find out):

     `$ docker-machine ssh default`
- 3. Change to root user([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646952/docker-machine-boot2docker-root-password)):

     `$ sudo -i`
- 4. Delete the log file content:

     `$ echo "" > log_file_path_from_step1`

Comment: docker-machine does not work with Docker for Mac. You can instead run "docker run -ti -v /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/inception centos bash" then "truncate --size 0  /var/inception/08d29a7d469232cfef4456dc6eebcbf313bf01ba73e479520a036150c5ab84de/08d29a7d469232cfef4456dc6eebcbf313bf01ba73e479520a036150c5ab84de-json.log"

Comment: You may use `docker exec -it default sh` to enter an sh shell in a container. However, many containers do not implicitly make the `sudo` command available.

Answer (score 2):

To remove/clear  docker container logs we can use below command

> $(docker inspect  container_id|grep "LogPath"|cut -d """ -f4)
> or
> $(docker inspect  container_name|grep "LogPath"|cut -d """ -f4)

Answer (score 1):

On computers with docker desktop we use:
`truncate -s 0 //wsl.localhost/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/containers/*/*-json.log`

For linux distributions you can use this it works for me with this path:
`truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log`

Answer (score 0):

If your host machine uses [systemd](https://systemd.io/), consider using [journald logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/).

This way you receive centralized log management, instead of silently logging to local un-rotated file ([default json-file logging driver does exactly this way](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)). In my case, using docker defaults led to diskspace exhausting (logfile eated over 7G).

Journald daemon can easily be configured to rotate logs, see [the docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html)

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a useful command, maybe it help someone.

```
`sudo sh -c "truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/**/*-json.log"`
```

You can use `rm -rf` /log dir, but make sure you know what to delete :).

Also  `docker system prune` removes unnecessary/unused images.

Answer (score -18):

`docker system prune`
run this command in command prompt

Comment: and then? it deletes the cache or all images? bad asnwer

Comment: docker system prune remove unused data

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/