# Docker: Error grabbing logs: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I upgraded my Docker version to the latest one and I got this error:

> error from daemon in stream: Error grabbing logs: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value

I can’t read logs using:

```
docker-compose logs -f myservice
```

nor with:

```
docker logs -f 6f454c73ff9c
```

Output of Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:18 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Output of Docker info:

```
Containers: 11
 Running: 11
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 8
Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 76
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-97-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.695GiB
Name: egmintel-desktop
ID: VB22:IXWI:GY6D:QPM4:SPHX:HYUP:OQN7:ZM55:LLKE:P3UU:XK7F:26TH
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
My docker-compose version:
docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21
```

I also noticed that one of my containers is not working properly (but I can't see the error since I can't read logs) and I need to restart the Docker service so my container starts working again.

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: See this link: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-daemon-error-invalid-character-x00-looking-for-beginning-of-value/18072/3

Comment: And this one: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1984

Answer (score 24):

Simply remove the ~/.docker/ directory.

Comment: Splendid, I had this problem on Windows and not even a full Docker reinstall helped, but this did (the folder is apparently kept even after factory reset and reinstall). My problem was with the `docker context ls` command, which broke the VSCode extension.

Comment: @JanPokorný Had the same situation as you. Thanks for the explanation, which will most likely help future readers!

Answer (score 23):

I resolve this with docker compose by simply down it and up again

```bash
docker compose down
docker compose up -d
```

Comment: This handled the issue for me, after trying to fiddle with the logs without success.

Comment: this helped, thank you!

Comment: This seems like the proper solution for this particular issue.

In my case, the containers were properly booting and staying up, but the `docker compose logs` functionality was failing. After properly shutting down the containers and booting them up again the issue was solved.

Answer (score 5):

a workaroud may be clear the broken log file.
// the log still can be read (by cat or vim), just docker can't handle it

### cmds

- get log path

```bash
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' YOUR_CONTAINER
```

- clear log
  before clear, backup it as you need

```
:> THE_LOG_PATH
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510314/4896468

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your events.log file got corrupted. Try deleting following file

1. "/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd/events.log"
2. restart the docker through init.d

Answer (score 3):

Using windows Docker Desktop

Troubleshoot -> Reset to factory defaults

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can clear your docker log with this:

```
cat /dev/null > $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' YOUR_DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME_HERE)
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows you need delete json file with `0x00` bytes
located in `%USERPROFILE%\.docker\contexts` folder and it's subdirs.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows
Delete this file, and restart containers

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This command will remove all \x00 bytes from all docker containers log files.

```
grep -r -l -a -P '\x00' /var/lib/docker/containers/ | xargs -I {} perl -pi -e 's/\x00//g' {}
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that work's :
--tail=10 flag (or whatever number you like) to only get the lines after the "invalid" character.

```
docker logs --tail=10
```

it work also with docker compose

found here https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/140#issuecomment-374930251