# docker container ls --size not accurate, how to get accurate container size?

Tags: docker

one of my docker container seems to grow and docker is not tracking the size. It will go up in size 20gigs in a few days and `docker container ls --size` still shows 1gb in size including virtual. I know it's 20gb because if I remove the container I get 20 gb freed. Is there a way to get an accurate measurement?

Comment: Did you try using `-a` flag?

Comment: do you use a Volume in your docker container ?

Comment: there's no volume, it's the official elasticsearch image

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the container log was growing over a few months, and now reaching a tipping point.

My solution is to truncate the logs file (:facepalm:) as described here: [How to clear the logs properly for a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510002/how-to-clear-the-logs-properly-for-a-docker-container)

## Verify logs size

check docker container sizes:

```
root@example:/var/lib/docker/containers# docker ps --size -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES               SIZE
0117e099a9b0        ix                      "/docker-entrypoin..."   8 months ago        Up 2 minutes        px                                         cx                  2B (virtual 132MB)
...
```

check actual disk usage:

```
root@example:/var/lib/docker/containers# find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec du -hs {} 2>/dev/null \;
45G     .
37G     ./0117e099a9b04a36817c9a51f20f89571baeb3fe1b2a011695929d9bf381600f
...
```

Dive into the culprit (`0117e099a9b0`) to see that the log file which is not measured:

```
root@example:/var/lib/docker/containers/0117e099a9b04a36817c9a51f20f89571baeb3fe1b2a011695929d9bf381600f# ls -lssh
total 37G
 37G -rw-r----- 1 root root  37G May 27 08:44 0117e099a9b04a36817c9a51f20f89571baeb3fe1b2a011695929d9bf381600f-json.log
...
```