# Docker : Overlay2 size too big

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running docker's environment with two containers.I noted the overlay2 folder size is too big. When the docker is down (docker-compose down) the overlay2 folder is 2.3GB size. When the containers are running, the overlay2 folder increase to 4.0GB and it's increasing by the time. Is it normal?

The command `du -shc /var/lib/docker/*` with the containers stoped:

```
76K     /var/lib/docker/buildkit
268K    /var/lib/docker/containers
3.7M    /var/lib/docker/image
64K     /var/lib/docker/network
2.3G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2
0       /var/lib/docker/plugins
0       /var/lib/docker/runtimes
0       /var/lib/docker/swarm
0       /var/lib/docker/tmp
0       /var/lib/docker/tmp-old
0       /var/lib/docker/trust
236M    /var/lib/docker/volumes
2.5G    total
```

The command `du -shc /var/lib/docker/*` with the containers running:

```
76K     /var/lib/docker/buildkit
448K    /var/lib/docker/containers
4.9M    /var/lib/docker/image
64K     /var/lib/docker/network
4.0G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2
0       /var/lib/docker/plugins
0       /var/lib/docker/runtimes
0       /var/lib/docker/swarm
0       /var/lib/docker/tmp
0       /var/lib/docker/tmp-old
0       /var/lib/docker/trust
235M    /var/lib/docker/volumes
4.3G    total
```

**EDIT**

The command `docker system df`

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          4         3         1.472GB   750.4MB (50%)
Containers      13        2         106.9MB   89.31MB (83%)
Local Volumes   62        1         1.884GB   1.817GB (96%)
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

Comment: Run `docker system df` rather.

Comment: I edited the question with the result.

Comment: So you have a lot of volumes, stopped containers and one unused images, which are why you have to much space taken.

Comment: Is it normal to increase the  overlay2 size when is running for 7 hour?

Comment: Depends what your container is doing. If you are logging in.a file inside the container, yes. Without more information, e.g. what is the _Dockerfile_ of the container, the base image, how is it used, etc. this would just be a guessing game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, run `docker system df`. It displays information regarding the amount of disk space used by the docker daemon. You can see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/).

Here is an example. You have 5 images, 2 actives and the local volume with one in inactive. So you can  reclaim a free space. For each type you can reclaim a free space.

1. **image** : you can remove images unused with the command line `docker image rmi <image name>`. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/)
2. **containers**: you can remove an inactive containers with the command line `docker container rm <container name>`. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_rm/)
3. **local volumes**: you can reclaim a free space using the command line `docker volume prune`. More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/)

[image]

After all these steps, you can check the Overlay2 consume. If it's ok or not: `du -shc /var/lib/docker/*` .

[image]

The garbage collection is a misterios in all tecnologias. You think it's work like this, but it works in other way around. You can learn more [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/).

**ATTENTION: Be careful using the `docker system prune`. Learn more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/).**

Answer (score 6):

This is an indication the container's read-write layer has files being written to it by the app running inside the container. You can see what files are being created/modified with:

```
docker container diff ${container_name_or_id}
```

for your specific containers. If your apps are writing logs to the container, I'd recommend against that (best practice is to write to stdout and then limit the size of those logs using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510314/596285)).

If the apps change permissions or ownership on a file, or make a small change to an otherwise large file, that will trigger a copy-on-write of the entire file, which can quickly increase the size on disk.

Typically you should avoid modifying files from your image. They should be static, where you could hopefully change the entire container filesystem to read-only. Configs would be injected externally (with a volume mount or environment variable), and data would be stored in either a volume or external database.

Answer (score 1):

/usr/var/docker is used to store images, the overlay2 contains various filesystem layers
use docker system prune

Comment: Thanks for your replay! I ran the docker prune, but the situation persist. I think there is something wrong.

Comment: I had the same problem: I ran `docker system prune --all --volumes`, the `docker system df` command said the size of what remained was much less than 1GB, yet `du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2` reported it was still taking 62GB of space!  I gave up, stopped docker, did `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` and started over, and when everything was running again, it took 4.6GB, although `docker system df` again added up to less than 1GB.