# What will happen if i delete a docker container log file?

Tags: docker, docker-logs

I have a simple question: what will happen if I delete a Docker container log file?
As we know Docker stores container log under `/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log`.
If by chance I deleted that `<container_name>-json.log` then what will happen? Docker will create a new log file or it will stop writing logs?

Comment: Try it and let us know :-)

Comment: My initial guess is that it's the same as any other Un*x file that's deleted while it's open for write: Docker will continue writing to the deleted file and it will keep taking up disk space, but it will not have an entry in the filesystem.  I haven't verified this, though.  How does your application code take advantage of this; can you include a code sample?

Comment: If you're having an issue with docker logs taking too much space, I'd suggest setting up automatic log rotation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510002/docker-how-to-clear-the-logs-properly-for-a-docker-container