# Can not login docker via ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-machine, swarm

I built docker swarm on my MacOS (version: 10.12.2) by `docker-machine` command following the office doc https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-w-machine/. I first create `swarm-master` and set its env variables, and it worked well, and then I continue to add swarm node `swarm-agent-00`, it also worked well. Then my Mac slowed down because of exhaustion of my memory. I restart my Mac by force to achieve the second swarm node `swarm-agent-01`. But when I return to start my `swarm-master`, it failed in the login step, I use optional `-D` to debug, and get the following log:

```
linzongshutekiMacBook-Air:~ root# docker-machine -D start swarm-master
Docker Machine Version:  0.8.2, build e18a919
Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:65359
() Calling .GetVersion
Using API Version  1
() Calling .SetConfigRaw
() Calling .GetMachineName
command=start machine=swarm-master
Starting "swarm-master"...
(swarm-master) Calling .GetState
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage showvminfo swarm-master --machinereadable
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | name="swarm-master"
(swarm-master) DBG | groups="/"
(swarm-master) DBG | ostype="Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64-bit)"
(swarm-master) DBG | UUID="1c319a99-23bc-457c-85a2-8eb84a219e38"
(swarm-master) DBG | CfgFile="/var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/swarm-master/swarm-master.vbox"
(swarm-master) DBG | SnapFldr="/var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/swarm-master/Snapshots"
(swarm-master) DBG | LogFldr="/var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/swarm-master/Logs"
(swarm-master) DBG | hardwareuuid="1c319a99-23bc-457c-85a2-8eb84a219e38"
(swarm-master) DBG | memory=1024
(swarm-master) DBG | pagefusion="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | vram=8
(swarm-master) DBG | cpuexecutioncap=100
(swarm-master) DBG | hpet="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | chipset="piix3"
(swarm-master) DBG | firmware="BIOS"
(swarm-master) DBG | cpus=1
(swarm-master) DBG | pae="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | longmode="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | triplefaultreset="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | apic="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | x2apic="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | cpuid-portability-level=0
(swarm-master) DBG | bootmenu="disabled"
(swarm-master) DBG | boot1="dvd"
(swarm-master) DBG | boot2="dvd"
(swarm-master) DBG | boot3="disk"
(swarm-master) DBG | boot4="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | acpi="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | ioapic="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | biosapic="apic"
(swarm-master) DBG | biossystemtimeoffset=0
(swarm-master) DBG | rtcuseutc="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | hwvirtex="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | nestedpaging="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | largepages="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | vtxvpid="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | vtxux="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | paravirtprovider="default"
(swarm-master) DBG | effparavirtprovider="kvm"
(swarm-master) DBG | VMState="poweroff"
(swarm-master) DBG | VMStateChangeTime="2016-12-27T02:22:44.927000000"
(swarm-master) DBG | monitorcount=1
(swarm-master) DBG | accelerate3d="off"
(swarm-master) Calling .Start
(swarm-master) DBG | accelerate2dvideo="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | teleporterenabled="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | teleporterport=0
(swarm-master) DBG | teleporteraddress=""
(swarm-master) DBG | teleporterpassword=""
(swarm-master) DBG | tracing-enabled="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | tracing-allow-vm-access="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | tracing-config=""
(swarm-master) DBG | autostart-enabled="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | autostart-delay=0
(swarm-master) DBG | defaultfrontend=""
(swarm-master) DBG | storagecontrollername0="SATA"
(swarm-master) DBG | storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci"
(swarm-master) DBG | storagecontrollerinstance0="0"
(swarm-master) DBG | storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30"
(swarm-master) DBG | storagecontrollerportcount0="30"
(swarm-master) DBG | storagecontrollerbootable0="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-0-0"="/var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/boot2docker.iso"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-0-0"="c0f13743-4448-4636-ab6b-343c424223ff"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-tempeject"="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-IsEjected"="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-1-0"="/var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/disk.vmdk"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-1-0"="77fcc5a6-5c88-4d04-ba03-b1136afc3fbe"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-2-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-3-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-4-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-5-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-6-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-7-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-8-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-9-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-10-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-11-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-12-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-13-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-14-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-15-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-16-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-17-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-18-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-19-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-20-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-21-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-22-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-23-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-24-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-25-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-26-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-27-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-28-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | "SATA-29-0"="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | natnet1="nat"
(swarm-master) DBG | macaddress1="080027E0FEBA"
(swarm-master) DBG | cableconnected1="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | nic1="nat"
(swarm-master) DBG | nictype1="82540EM"
(swarm-master) DBG | nicspeed1="0"
(swarm-master) DBG | mtu="0"
(swarm-master) DBG | sockSnd="64"
(swarm-master) DBG | sockRcv="64"
(swarm-master) DBG | tcpWndSnd="64"
(swarm-master) DBG | tcpWndRcv="64"
(swarm-master) DBG | Forwarding(0)="ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,52348,,22"
(swarm-master) DBG | hostonlyadapter2="vboxnet0"
(swarm-master) DBG | macaddress2="0800275C28CA"
(swarm-master) DBG | cableconnected2="on"
(swarm-master) DBG | nic2="hostonly"
(swarm-master) DBG | nictype2="82540EM"
(swarm-master) DBG | nicspeed2="0"
(swarm-master) DBG | nic3="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | nic4="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | nic5="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | nic6="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | nic7="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | nic8="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | hidpointing="ps2mouse"
(swarm-master) DBG | hidkeyboard="ps2kbd"
(swarm-master) DBG | uart1="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | uart2="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | uart3="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | uart4="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | lpt1="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | lpt2="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | audio="none"
(swarm-master) DBG | clipboard="disabled"
(swarm-master) DBG | draganddrop="disabled"
(swarm-master) DBG | vrde="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | usb="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | ehci="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | xhci="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="Users"
(swarm-master) DBG | SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="/Users"
(swarm-master) DBG | vcpenabled="off"
(swarm-master) DBG | vcpscreens=0
(swarm-master) DBG | vcpfile="/var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/swarm-master/swarm-master.webm"
(swarm-master) DBG | vcpwidth=1024
(swarm-master) DBG | vcpheight=768
(swarm-master) DBG | vcprate=512
(swarm-master) DBG | vcpfps=25
(swarm-master) DBG | GuestMemoryBalloon=0
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
...
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage list hostonlyifs
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | Name:            vboxnet0
(swarm-master) DBG | GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
(swarm-master) DBG | DHCP:            Disabled
(swarm-master) DBG | IPAddress:       192.168.99.1
(swarm-master) DBG | NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
(swarm-master) DBG | IPV6Address:     
(swarm-master) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
(swarm-master) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
(swarm-master) DBG | MediumType:      Ethernet
(swarm-master) DBG | Status:          Up
(swarm-master) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0
(swarm-master) DBG | 
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | Searching for hostonly interface for IPv4: 192.168.99.1 and Mask: ffffff00
(swarm-master) DBG | Found: vboxnet0
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage list dhcpservers
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | NetworkName:    HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0
(swarm-master) DBG | IP:             192.168.99.6
(swarm-master) DBG | NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
(swarm-master) DBG | lowerIPAddress: 192.168.99.100
(swarm-master) DBG | upperIPAddress: 192.168.99.254
(swarm-master) DBG | Enabled:        Yes
(swarm-master) DBG | 
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | Removing orphan DHCP servers...
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage list hostonlyifs
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | Name:            vboxnet0
(swarm-master) DBG | GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
(swarm-master) DBG | DHCP:            Disabled
(swarm-master) DBG | IPAddress:       192.168.99.1
(swarm-master) DBG | NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
(swarm-master) DBG | IPV6Address:     
(swarm-master) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
(swarm-master) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
(swarm-master) DBG | MediumType:      Ethernet
(swarm-master) DBG | Status:          Up
(swarm-master) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0
(swarm-master) DBG | 
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | Adding/Modifying DHCP server "192.168.99.6"...
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage list dhcpservers
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | NetworkName:    HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0
(swarm-master) DBG | IP:             192.168.99.6
(swarm-master) DBG | NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
(swarm-master) DBG | lowerIPAddress: 192.168.99.100
(swarm-master) DBG | upperIPAddress: 192.168.99.254
(swarm-master) DBG | Enabled:        Yes
(swarm-master) DBG | 
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm swarm-master --nic2 hostonly --nictype2 82540EM --nicpromisc2 deny --hostonlyadapter2 vboxnet0 --cableconnected2 on
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm swarm-master --natpf1 delete ssh
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage modifyvm swarm-master --natpf1 ssh,tcp,127.0.0.1,52348,,22
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage startvm swarm-master --type headless
(swarm-master) DBG | STDOUT:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | Waiting for VM "swarm-master" to power on...
(swarm-master) DBG | VM "swarm-master" has been successfully started.
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | STDERR:
(swarm-master) DBG | {
(swarm-master) DBG | }
(swarm-master) DBG | Checking vm logs: /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/swarm-master/Logs/VBox.log
(swarm-master) Waiting for an IP...
(swarm-master) DBG | Getting to WaitForSSH function...
(swarm-master) DBG | Using SSH client type: external
(swarm-master) DBG | Using SSH private key: /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa (-rw-------)
(swarm-master) DBG | &{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa -p 52348] /usr/bin/ssh <nil>}
(swarm-master) DBG | About to run SSH command:
(swarm-master) DBG | exit 0
(swarm-master) DBG | SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255: 
(swarm-master) DBG | Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : Something went wrong running an SSH command!
(swarm-master) DBG | command : exit 0
(swarm-master) DBG | err     : exit status 255
(swarm-master) DBG | output  : 
(swarm-master) DBG | 
(swarm-master) DBG | Getting to WaitForSSH function...
(swarm-master) DBG | Using SSH client type: external
(swarm-master) DBG | Using SSH private key: /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa (-rw-------)
(swarm-master) DBG | &{[-F /dev/null -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -o ConnectionAttempts=3 -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none docker@127.0.0.1 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa -p 52348] /usr/bin/ssh <nil>}
(swarm-master) DBG | About to run SSH command:
(swarm-master) DBG | exit 0
(swarm-master) DBG | SSH cmd err, output: exit status 255: 
(swarm-master) DBG | Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : Something went wrong running an SSH command!
(swarm-master) DBG | command : exit 0
(swarm-master) DBG | err     : exit status 255
(swarm-master) DBG | output  :
```

The shell was continuing `Getting to WaitForSSH function...` and return `Error getting ssh command 'exit 0' : Something went wrong running an SSH command!` and finally exit with error message `Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded`.

But machine was running with empty URL, Then I try the other two swarm node, and they logged in successfully and can be activated as well. Here are machine lists (the agent-01 was stopped due to lack of memory):

```
linzongshutekiMacBook-Air:~ root# docker-machine ls
NAME             ACTIVE      DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM                   DOCKER    ERRORS
default          -           virtualbox   Stopped                                                       Unknown   
local            -           virtualbox   Stopped                                                       Unknown   
swarm-agent-00   -           virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.102:2376   swarm-master            v1.12.5   
swarm-agent-01   -           virtualbox   Stopped                               swarm-master            Unknown   
swarm-master     * (swarm)   virtualbox   Running                               swarm-master (master)   Unknown   Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
```

By viewing the log above, I found there was a step to log in localhost by SSH, then I run the command directly in terminal with log info, and outputs are:

```
linzongshutekiMacBook-Air:~ root# ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa -p 52348 docker@127.0.0.1 -vvv
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "127.0.0.1" port 52348
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 52348.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:52348 as 'docker'
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:52348
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:67
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [127.0.0.1]:52348
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:suSnsokwsrM9SiXN+LGUnF+3h698gOhqaQqGQBsECiY
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:52348
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:52348
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:67
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [127.0.0.1]:52348
debug1: Host '[127.0.0.1]:52348' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:67
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa (0x7f93e9410560), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

The I googled around and someone said these log don't have anything useful, it should to refer logs of sshd in remote server. It make me confused because I didn't even found a log of ssh from my Mac, and I didn't know how to go on debug?

Of course, I can remove the master machine and create a new one, but it is better for me to find the reason. Can someone tell me what's the problem and how to fix it? More details about how docker processing `docker` user log in maybe so much the better. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With more search and debug, I found docker-machine is a linux liked virtual machine (not very exactly), and it also contains users and auth users, the following question show that password of `docker` user is `tcuser`, and I tried it, it logged successfully:

```
ssh -p 52348 docker@127.0.0.1
```

Reference: [How do I SSH into the boot2docker host vm that the Vagrant 1.6 Docker Provider sets up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286007/how-do-i-ssh-into-the-boot2docker-host-vm-that-the-vagrant-1-6-docker-provider-s)

Then I found `/home/docker` donot contain `.ssh` file, so I copy the public key by following commands in local terminal:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa.pub -p 52348 docker@127.0.0.1
```

Then it can be logged by:

```
ssh -i /var/root/.docker/machine/machines/swarm-master/id_rsa.pub -p 52348 docker@127.0.0.1
```

But certs need to regenerated before you set docker environment variables:

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs swarm-master
eval "$(docker-machine env swarm-master)"
```

Finally, `swarm-master` running well:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME             ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM                   DOCKER    ERRORS
...
swarm-agent-01   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.103:2376       swarm-master            v1.12.5   
swarm-master     *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376   swarm-master (master)   v1.12.5
```

But, it came across a new question, the `.ssh` folder will be removed each time `swarm-master` restart, then I need to redo the above operation to make it work, 
can some one show me why, and how can I resolve the problem thoroughly?